# MVC ResetPasswordAsync not working across different website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have 2 web applications having exactly the same code, just different authentication method deployed across Azure, namely site A(forms authentication) and Site B(windows authentication)

this is the code segment to generate the token, i have the identical code in 2 different controllers
Account and AdminReset

```
var UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
```

my code for resetting the password is (in Account controller) -

```
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(model.UserId, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(model.Code), model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //do something
                }
```

i am having problem when i am generating the token from site B as the admin for the user(which generates password reset url on site A), when i try to reset the password on site A, it prompts the token is invalid.

It works fine if i am generating the token on Site A as the normal user, and resets it in Site A..

Is it due to the token are generated across different websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate a token using the GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync call, ASP.NET Identity creates an encrypted token using built in [Data Protection APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

The Data Protection APIs use a "Key Ring" to encrypt and decrypt the token. By default, this "Key Ring" is stored locally on the server file system. This behavior is documented [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> The ASP.NET Core Data Protection system is used by apps to protect data. Data Protection relies upon a set of cryptographic keys stored in a key ring. When the Data Protection system is initialized, it applies default settings that store the key ring locally. Under the default configuration, a unique key ring is stored on each node of the web farm. Consequently, each web farm node can't decrypt data that's encrypted by an app on any other node.

In your scenario, because the reset token is being generated in Site B and then being used in Site A, the token cannot be decrypted. Site A does not know how to decrypt a token generated by Site B because they do not share the same "Key Ring".

In order to fix this, you need to configure both Site A and Site B to use a central (secure) location to store the "Key Ring" as outlined [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0)